# discord.py discord-slash import

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot with Discord.py, and I cant use discord-slash. I tried to install the pip. I will add pics (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ygwM.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sBMO.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci4WB.png)

Don't ask about the bot name, it was a discord bot for a Minecraft server originally...

I added the pip install pics up there and the import...